# Running api fetch on entering screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating an app in React Native (create react native) and I am attempting to fetch data from an API every time a user transitions to a screen.

For navigation, I am using the React Navigation library with a combination of Drawer and Stack Navigators.

Typically, I have seen fetch handled via the ComponentDidMount() lifecycle. However, when navigating to a screen in a stack navigator, the ComponentDidMount() lifecycle doesn't appear to trigger and the fetch doesn't run.

Ex. user is on post index, then navigates to add post screen, submits and is redirected to view screen (for that post), then clicks back to return to index. Returning to index does not trigger ComponentDidMount() and fetch isn't run again, so results are not updated.

Additionally, sometimes I need to access navigation params to alter a fetch request when navigation between screens.

I originally was attempting to determine screen transition (when navigation params were passed) via `componentWillReceiveProps()` method, however, this seemed a bit unreliable.

I did more reading and it sounds like I should be subscribing to listeners (via react navigation). I am having a hard time finding recent examples.

***Current process (example)***

On the desired screen I would subscribe to listener(s) in the componentDidMount() method:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = [this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => this.setup(payload))];
  }
```

Based of an example, it sounds like its good practice to remove all subs when unmounting the screen, so I also add:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.forEach((sub) => {
      sub.remove();
    });
  }
```

then I add a setup() callback method that calls whatever fetch methods I require:

```
setup = (payload) => {
    this.getExampleDataFromApi();
  };
```

Additionally, sometimes I need to access Navigation params that will be used in API queries.

I am setting these params via methods in other screens like so:

```
  goToProfile = (id) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
      exampleParam: 'some value',
    });
  };
```

It seems like I cannot access the navigation prop via the provided `getParam()` method when within callback method from a navigation listener.

For example, this returns undefined.

```
setup = (payload) => {
    console.log(navigation.getParam('exampleParam', []));
  };
```

Instead I am having to do

```
componentDidFocus = (payload) => {
    console.log(payload.action.params.exampleParam);
  };
```

***Question***

I wanted to ask if my approach for handling fetch when navigating seems appropriate, and if not, what is a better way to tackle handling API requests when navigating between screens?

Thanks, I really appreciate the help!